# UIButton set image for state normal, hide that image in different states

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

```
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle: @"Title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I would like the button to display the image in normal state but the word "Title" in selected state. But I can't get this code to work. It displays Image when I click the button to selected state and the Image covers the title.  I can't get rid of the image in selected state.

```
 [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

But this works.  The image flips from Back to Back2.  Or the other way works too

```
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle: @"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is so simple and I started to think it is UIButton bug.
Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 4):

Add some small transparent image (1px is enough) to your project and name it, for example, transparent.png. Then add this line to the code:

```objectivec
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The other and much simpler solution is to use interface builder and set images for diferent states. In this case you even don't need to use the transparent image; simply left the Image field empty for Selected state.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like @codeplasma answer, but no need to add a transparent image, just create an empty `UIImage`:

```swift
button.setImage(UIImage(), forState: .selected)
```

In Objective-C you would create it with `[UIImage new]`.

Comment: Awesome..!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set the button state to selected in some UIButtons(like the rounded rect button), it does not happen automatically upon clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

### Bug?

No, it's not a bug, UIButton is designed this way, and here's why: when you set an image for the `UIButton`'s `UIControlStateNormal` (normal state), it will preserve it throughout the other states (selected, disabled, highlighted) in the event you did not specify an image for those other states.

This means you can set up your button with a single image, the system adds a dark highlight in highlight state and makes the button look like it's alpha 0.5 in disabled state.

You might think setting the image to `nil` for the selected state will get rid of it for that state, but of course when the state changes, it will see that it doesn't have an image for that state (it's `nil` !), but it does for state `UIControlStateNormal`, so it will use that one instead, thus you are stuck with the same image!

Note that if you set the image for a different state then normal, it would have only shown for that state.

### Workaround

Honestly your intentions with the button's image/title sound a little odd... Maybe you're new to iOS, maybe with some more info about what your button is and is supposed to be doing, we can suggest a better solution.... but the easiest way to workaround this with the information you've given us is to give a valid image for the selected state, one which is preferably transparent, and it could be 1x1 pixels also to save on space.

Otherwise you can do this, create a `UIImage` at runtime to use as a placeholder acting as your image, but *would be a good idea to cache this, perhaps create it once and hold it in an iVar*.

```
// Create a 1x1 UIImage at runtime
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((CGSize){1.0f,1.0f});
UIImage *runtimeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Setup your button 
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0);

// set the image for each state
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:runtimeImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

// have your text for the normal state
[btn setTitle:@"selected !" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. you are right about me new to iOS.  It is my homework to design a card game in which the user clicks the card to reveal its self(the title) and clicks again to turn the card face down. I will try ur transparent image workaround.  The professor hints it would be tricky and he claims to use two lines to set the image for appropriate states.  Wonder how he did that.

Comment: You should look at UITapGestureRecognizer. You could just have an image view with your card image, and a label on top which is hidden. Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the card image view and toggle the label to show/hide. Really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setImage, I suggest to use SetBackgroundImage for this scenario. Here is a solution that works for me for a similar solution:

```
UIImage *cardBackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"];
UIImage *cardFrontImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];

[cardButton setBackgroundImage:cardFrontImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cardButton setBackgroundImage:cardFrontImage forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];

[cardButton setBackgroundImage:cardBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```